# How to dismiss @synthesize directives from Function Menu

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode4.3

We use `#pragma mark - StackOverFlow Example` in order to organize our Function Menu (the most-inner menu in the implementation navigation menu).

What I want to do is to simplify the Function Menu by removing unwanted directives such as `@synthesize` or maybe could we use any ignore key to ignore a code segment partially from the  Function Menu ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to write `@synthesize` statement in one line.
Then it will show up with only one line.

Comment: this seems to be the most elegant way to solve this (Below XCode 4.4). Thanks !

Comment: Well make it sure that you no longer need to synthesize properties in ios5. If you create a property and do not synthesize it, then compiler will create an ivar for you with underscore prefixed name. :)

Answer (score 4):

Well, as of Xcode 4.4 you no longer need to `@synthesize` your properties. The compiler will do it for you automatically, so you can remove them and therefore remove them from your drop down. Keep in mind you need to be using the LLVM 4.0 compiler for this feature.

`@property NSString *string;`

Will automatically cause the compiler to do the equivalent of `@synthesize string = _string;` in your implementation

Comment: which means, below Xcode 4.4, there is no way of doing it, right?

Comment: I believe that statement is correct, unless there is someway to use the LLVM 4.0 compiler in a previous version.

Comment: You *can* mix and match compiler/IDE versions, but there's not really any point since you must use the latest IDE and SDK for all App Store submissions.

Comment: There is still a case where you must explicitly synthesize a property: When you implement both the getter and the setter!

Answer (score 2):

You can't hide a declaration from the Function menu; it's there to help, not to confuse if something is not listed when it belongs in that file.

As such, there are a couple of options you have:

1. Remove the `@synthesize` completely. recent versions of Xcode with LLVM 4.0 means that these directives are no longer required, properties will synthesise themselves. This mightn't be an easy change if you have manually declared the backing instance variable, and reference that throughout your code. i.e.

   ```
   @synthesize myProperty = m_myProperty;

   m_myProperty = ...;
   ```
2. Insert a `#pragma mark -` before and after the synthesis of your properties, to try and split them away from the other methods.

This is the best you can do I'm afraid, there isn't any other `#pragma` directives that can remove something from the Function list.